# Chaning hide/show method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to chain the `hide()` and `show` method into a single statement?.

```
$("#icon").on('click', function(){    
     $("#form").hide();   
     $('.nav-row').show();
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML

Comment: If you're applying the methods on different objects, why do you need chaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callback functions to get timing down for chains.

http://jsfiddle.net/qEZ6y/4/

```
$("#icon").on('click', function(){    
    $("#form").hide(function(){
        $('.nav-row').show();    
    });   
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I think this would do the job,

```
$("#form, .nav-row").toggle();
```